# Post variables from js to form and then to php file

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables, post

first of all, greetings and excuse my English...
I explain my problem:
I have some JS functions that generate some variables, I would like to send these variables via the POST method to a php file to be consulted in a database...
I have read that the best way to do this is sending the variables to the respective values ​​about inputs within a form, Below I show the variables and  the form:

**Javascript variables:**
On click in "Buscar"

```
            $('#Buscar').on('click', function () {
            document.getElementById("tipo").value=TipoDeInmuebleDATA.selectedData.value;
            document.getElementById("operacion").value=TipoDeOperacionDATA.selectedData.value;
            document.getElementById("habitaciones").value=HabitacionesDATA.selectedData.value;
            document.getElementById("MetrosCuadrados").value=MetrosCuadrados;
            document.getElementById("banos").value=BanosDATA.selectedData.value;
            document.getElementById("precio").value=Precio;
});
```

**The Form:**

```
        <form name="FormBuscar" method="post" action="consulta.php">
            <input id="tipo" name="tipo" type="hidden" />
            <input id="operacion" name="operacion" type="hidden" />
            <input id="MetrosCuadrados" name="MetrosCuadrados" type="hidden" />
            <input id="habitaciones" name="habitaciones" type="hidden" />
            <input id="banos" name="banos" type="hidden" />
            <input id="precio" name="precio" type="hidden" />
            <input type="submit" name="Buscar" class="BotonBuscar">
        </form>
```

I suspect that something is wrong, in the sense that I think the variables are not being sent to consultation
In consultation, if I do the following:

```
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
echo $tipo;
```

No result :-(

Greetings, I will await your answers in!

Comment: There are multiple errors here. The JS syntax is incorrect, and it doesn't look like it would do anything useful anyway. You should post the entire PHP file and the JS and the HTML. Otherwise, you won't get a good answer.

Comment: My goal is to find the right way to rewrite the "value" property of my inputs with the values ​​of the variables in javascript.

Comment: I think you want to change `name="Buscar"` to `id="Buscar"`

Comment: Mike, this is the answer "I think you want to change name="Buscar" to id="Buscar"", Thank you!

Comment: Mike, Post reply to mark it! :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is wrong. You want to change the values right before submitting. So also add `id="buscar-form"` to the form tag. Then you can change the jQuery to this:

```
$('#buscar-form').on('submit', function () {
  $('#tipo').val(TipoDeInmuebleDATA.selectedData.value);
  $('#operacion').val(TipoDeInmuebleDATA.selectedData.value);
  ...
});
```

Forget about the #buscar button. When you click the button, the form is going to submit. So that's the event captured above. Careful with your typing, there are a lot of typos!